# Comparing two url-slugs to find count of same words

Tags: mysql

I want to find similar posts on my website depending on the url slug.
say i have the following five slugs

```
i-am-a-slug         /*the slug i want to compare*/
i-am-another-slug   /* 3 same words */
i-am-an-ant         /* 2 same words */    
the-slug-life       /* 1 same word */
foo-bar             /* 0 same words */
```

at the moment i am using the following code to find out if there are any similar words in the compared slug

```
SELECT *
FROM News
WHERE News.slug != "i-am-a-slug"
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN News.slug REGEXP "i|am|a|slug" THEN 1
ELSE 2
```

it doesn't even work very well... words like the `a` in the example give back hits in nearly every slug i have in my database... in the example, even the slug `foo-bar` would be returned.

i can't seem to figure out how to select a variable `same-words-count` that counts all the same words within each tested slug (see comments first code-block for the solutions i would like to get), so i could

```
SELECT *
FROM News
WHERE News.slug != "i-am-a-slug"
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN same-words-count > 2 THEN 1
WHEN same-words-count = 2 THEN 2
WHEN same-words-count = 1 THEN 3
ELSE 4
```

or is there an even better way to do this?

thank you very much in advance, sorry my mysql is a bit rusty lately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called inverted index: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Depending on the data amount and what you actually are going to do with the result (do you need to keep it up to date, do you need to show it on the site, etc) you might want to solve the problem using a programming language of your choice or use some full-blown fulltext search solution. Plain SQL just isn't a right tool for this.

Comment: I want to show only similar uris on my website. I'll probably just `SELECT` all the slugs and then use `php` for the sorting... thank you